# How can I underline the active link in my side nav bar? Using material design in angular app

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<div class="mt-3">
  <mat-nav-list>

      <a mat-list-item class="ml-2" style="font-size:15px;" (click)='paycard.html'>
          SERVICE
        </a>
      <a mat-list-item class="ml-2" style="font-size:15px;" (click)='paycard.html'>
          BILLING
        </a>
      <a mat-list-item class="ml-2" style="font-size:15px;" (click)='paycard.html'>
          OIL TICKETS
        </a>
      <a mat-list-item class="ml-2" style="font-size:15px;" (click)='paycard.html'>
          MY TIME
        </a>
      <a mat-list-item class="ml-2" style="font-size:15px;" (click)='paycard.html'>
          APPROVE TIME
        </a>
      <a mat-list-item class="ml-2" style="font-size:15px;" (click)='paycard.html'>
          EMPLOYEE LIST
        </a>
```

snippet of my html navigation page I just want to underline the active link but not quite sure how to do that within an angular app using material design. Also if there is a way to collapse it I would like to know that too. Thank you.

Comment: What's `(click)='paycard.html'` ?

Comment: its just there for now I am eventually going to change to where it redirects to

Comment: it is only there for a placeholder at the moment

Comment: You can use router for navigation https://angular.io/guide/router and  `routerLinkActive="active"`(for e.g.) in HTML and class `active` in your css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As found in the Angular [Routing and Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router) documentation, you use the `routerLinkActive` directive.

```
<mat-nav-list>
   <a mat-list-item 
        routerLink="/paycard"
        routerLinkActive="active_route"> Paycard </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

This will add the `.active_route` class to your active route. Then you can style it as you'd like:

```
.active_route {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If you have similar links, you may need to use `{pathMatch: full}` in the router link options (eg if you have routes "/pay" and "/pay/card".)

Answer (score 0):

If you do the routing in the tag you can add the `routerLinkActive`attribute to apply a css class when the route is active.

In you case the would look something like this:

```
    <a mat-list-item class="ml-2" style="font-size:15px;" (click)='paycard.html'
 routerLink="service" routerLinkActive="<css class you want to apply when active"> SERVICE </a>
```

For more information have a look [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)